# FactoryGirl on polymorphic association

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I need to find the best way to build my model objects.
I inherited the code base, it is not very pretty.

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :author_id, :notifable_id, :notifable_type, :seen, :user_id
   belongs_to :notifiable, :polymorphic => true
```

So author_id and user_id are implicit pointers to the user model

```
#A user 
has_many :notifications
```

The polymorphic relation notifiable allows to have the like model notifiable for instance.
When you like a post, you create a notifiable like and a notification that has an author and a receiver (user_id)

I have trouble to create a factory for a user that have a notification (that is the receiver of the notification)

```
factory :notification do |f|
  n = FactoryGirl.generate(:number_notification)
  user = create(:user)
  #author_id
  f.author_id user.id
  f.user_id :user_dest
  f.association :user, user
end

factory :notification_like, parent: :notification  do |f|
  f.notifiable_type "Like"
  f.notifiable_id 1
end
```

this code does not work. It complains on user.id, saying it does not exists.

My feature test look like this:

```
let(:max) { create(:user) }
let(:notification) { create(:notification_like, :user_dest => max.id) }
let(:login_page) { HomeLoginPage.new }
let(:main_page) { MainPage.new }

scenario "login" do
  notification
  login_page.visit_page.login(max)
  main_page
  sleep(60)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [callbacks](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks) to make your associations work.

```
factory :notification do |f|
  FactoryGirl.generate(:number_notification)
  user

  after(:build) do |notification|
    notification.author_id = notification.user.id
    notification.user_id = notification.user.id
  end
end
```